# How to select multiple deep DOM using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, dom

I have multiple level DOM elements, But I still finding how to select DOM element.
My html here.

```
<div class="data">
  <div class="item">
    <form class="comment" method="post" action="">
      <div class="d1">
        <a href="">Tree</a>
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="d2">
        <p class="quote">
      </div>
      <div class="col p3">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value=""/><input type="hidden" name="u" value=""/><input type="button" class="button" name="submit"/><br>
        <abbr class="selected_dom" title="2012-07-05T11:29:22Z">July 1, 2012</abbr>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please help me how to select this `<abbr class="selected_dom" title="2012-07-05T11:29:22Z">July 1, 2012</abbr>` ?

Comment: Please [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it's *far* easier to answer a question if it can be easily read.

Comment: Recommend either always using `</p>` (my preference), or never using it, but not using it *sometimes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
// select abbr element with class selected_dom, inside form with class comment
var abbr = $('form.comment abbr.selected_dom');
```

Depending on your HTML structure, you may just want to select `abbr` elements:

```
var abbr = $('abbr');
```

Read more about [selectors (general)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)